# How do I get Mac to look for plugins in the Program.App/Contents/Plugins directory?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, gcc

I have a Qt application which links to `libqjpeg.dylib`. On the development machine, the libraries are in `/Applications/Qt/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/plugins/imageformats`. I placed the libraries in the `Program.App/Contents/Plugins` directory on the target machine.

However, when I run it through strace (dtruss on mac) I can see that the application only stats

- `/Applications/Qt/Desktop/Qt/4.8.0/gcc/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib`
- `/Users/USER/lib/libqjpeg.dylib`
- `/usr/local/lib/libqjpeg.dylib`
- `/usr/lib/libqjpeg.dylib`

How can I get it to look for the plugin in the `Program.App/Contents/Plugins` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think it's more standard to put dylibs in Contents/Frameworks rather than Contents/Plugins.

Second, the install path for the dylib is recorded in the dylib itself.  You can change that path using the `install_name_tool` command, like so:

```
install_name_tool -id @loader_path/../Frameworks/libqjpeg.dylib libqjpeg.dylib
```

Then link your app against that modified copy of libqjpeg.dylib.

Comment: Thanks for this bit of the puzzle: the only problem is that on the development machine the libraries will be in the previous path mentioned. Is there any way to make it check both?

Comment: I think you can do that using @rpath.  See [this blog post](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/11/15/rpath/) for an explanation.